# I upgraded bitcoind to 0.8 from 0.7, may I delete the old blocks?

Tags: bitcoind

Upgrading to 0.8 from 0.7 I noticed the old `blk*.dat` files were untouched, while it was created a new directory called `blocks/`.

I guess I can delete the old `blk*.dat` files? Is there something else I'm supposed to delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you don't plan on switching back to the old version you can delete the old blk*.dat files.

The final 0.8 release will include this little script to tidy your data directory:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/contrib/tidy_datadir.sh

Comment: Thanks.  I must have skipped 0.8 because I still had those files there in 0.12.1.  Note I believe you can also safely delete blkindex.dat, addr.dat and db.log if they're still lingering in your Data directory.